# Puppeteer trigger function in node to run from browser event

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I would like to trigger a function that runs in node from the browser. How can I do this?

```
  let log = () => console.log("helsadfl");

  await page.evaluate((log) => {
    document.addEventListener("click", function () {
      console.log(log);
    });
  }, log);
```

Additional:
Why is this not able to console.log the target?

```
  await page.exposeFunction("log", (e) => console.log(e.target));

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", log);
  });
```

Comment: If you're using puppeteer wouldnt that imply you are not using a browser? I'm confused

Comment: I want a click event in the browser to trigger a function in Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction):

```js
await page.exposeFunction('log', () => console.log("helsadfl"));

await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    await window.log();
  });
});
```

Comment: It works! What is the purpose of await on the window.log function ?

Comment: It is just for an illustration that the function returns a promise. It can be omitted if you need not the value the promise is resolved into.

Comment: I added an additional related question to my post. Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: @yyyyrrrrreee As with `page.evaluate()`, only serializable values can be transferred between Node.js and browser contexts via exposed function. `e` is event, it may be not serializable (it has methods and maybe cyclic references).